# Page is not loading properly with editor.html in the url AEM6.1

Tags: aem

My page is not loading properly with the url having "editor.html" (http://localhost:4502/editor.html/content/mypage.html). But when I remove editor.html, it loads perfectly (http://localhost:4502/content/mypage.html).
I am using AEM6.1. If I open the page in classic UI, its looks good. But when I open it in touch UI, its not loading properly.

1. I already have a property "sling:resourceSuperType = wcm/foundation/components/page"
2. Some of the content is coming on the page.
3. It can be a JS issue, but even if I remove all the js files from my component, the issue is still there.

Anyone experienced the same issue?

Comment: Can you provide snapshot of page with and without editor.html? Why do you need wcm/foundation/components/page ? foundation/components/page is also capable of supporting TouchUI and Sightly?

Comment: Yeah! I have tried with " foundation/components/page" too. But, got the same output. When "editor.html" is there in the url, images and texts are not being loaded properly, but the style of the page(css) is being loaded perfectly.

Comment: We had a similar issue before and resolved it with removing the editor.html folder under "/libs/wcm/core/content/". I don't know if that is the case for you but it worths trying. I don't know why that folder is created.

Comment: I actually don't see "editor.html" folder under "/libs/wcm/core/content". There is a node "editor" of type cq:page. Are you referring to this node?

Comment: Did you find any solution, facing the same issue!!!!

Answer (score 2):

This issue might be due to the 'Apache Sling Main Servlet' default configuration.

And also we can observe the error message 'components could not be loaded' or 'out of memory' in browser console when we are in Touch UI  editor Mode.

By default 'Apache Sling Main Servlet' is configured with 1000 calls per request. If we increase this limit then the issue will be resolved.

```
For updating this follow the steps.
1. Go to the http://<host>:<port-number>/system/console/configMgr (ex: http://localhost:4502/system/console/configMgr)
2. Ctrl + F and Search for "Apache Sling Main Servlet".
3. Change the value of 'Number of Calls per Request' from 1000 (defaulut value) to 1500 or 2000.
4. Click on Save.
5. Now you can go to Touch UI edit mode and can be able to edit the components.
```

[image]

Comment: This change did something definitely in my case, after few reloads it started to work again,

Answer (score 0):

Check in your CRXDE under the folder /libs/wcm/core/content and look for a folder called "editor.html" with the sibling of just "editor". If you delete the editor.html folder and keep "editor", then your page will start working again.